# Draw a polyline after every 10 seconds on google map in andriod

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, polyline

I have made an application in which user's location is fetched after every 10 seconds once the start button is pressed and a polyline is drawn from old to new location untill stop button is pressed. 
now the problem is when the polyline code is inside the run function, there is no line drawn on the map. but if i put that code outside the run function, it is working fine (like when i re-presss the start button i get the polyline) but i don't want to press the button every single time, i want that line to be drawn on it's own through a timer.

here is my code

```
    track_record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Your Tracking is started now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                ///////*************************************////////
                                                // create class object
                                                gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
                                                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                                                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
                                                    @Override

                                                    public void run() {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run() {

                                                                LatLng current =   new LatLng(latitude = gps.getLatitude(),longitude = gps.getLongitude());

                                                                if (begin == 0) {
                                                               fixedBegin = current;

                                                                    // create marker
                                                                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(fixedBegin).title("Begin ");

                                                                    // Changing the color babyyy
                                                                  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                                                    // adding marker
                                                                mMap.addMarker(marker);


                                                                    // Not working here, but should be

                                                                    if(Flag==0)  //when the first update comes, we have no previous points,hence this
                                                                    {
                                                                        prev=current;
                                                                        Flag=1;
                                                                    }
                                                                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 16);
                                                                    mMap.animateCamera(update);
                                                                    mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                                                                            .add(prev, current).width(6).color(Color.BLUE)
                                                                            .visible(true));
                                                                    prev=current;
                                                                    current = null;

                                                              }
                                                                begin++;

                                                                Log.i("OK", "lat------ " + latitude);
                                                                Log.i("OK", "lng-------- " + longitude);

                                                                arrLat.add(latitude);
                                                                arrLng.add(longitude);

                                                                //////////// TRYING ///////////
                                                                // And it Worked here

/*
                                                                if(Flag==0)  //when the first update comes, we have no previous points,hence this
                                                                {
                                                                    prev=current;
                                                                    Flag=1;
                                                                }
                                                                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 16);
                                                                mMap.animateCamera(update);
                                                                mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                                                                        .add(prev, current).width(6).color(Color.BLUE)
                                                                        .visible(true));
                                                                prev=current;
                                                                current = null;
*/


                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                    }
                                                }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);


                                                // check if GPS enabled
                                                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                                                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                                                    String longlat = String.valueOf(latitude) + ":" + String.valueOf(longitude);
                                                    cordsList.add(longlat);
                                                    // \n is for new line
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry cant get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    // can't get location
                                                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                                                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                                                    // gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                                }

                                                Log.i("Finall", "Location-> " + cordsList.toString());

                                            }
                                        }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Handler for this purpose.

class variables.

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;
int t=0;
```

Use a Handler to with a delay of 10 seconds to draw polylines using lat and long

```
m_handler = new Handler();
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
@Override 
public void run() { 
if(t<listPoint.size()-1)
{     
LatLng src = listPoint.get(t);
LatLng dest = listPoint.get(t + 1);
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
    new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude))                                       
    .width(2).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true)); 
    t++;
    }
    else
    {
   m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
    } 
   m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 10000);    
    }
};
m_handlerTask.run();
```

Comment: We considering listPoint has list of latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: right. can you please specify where am i supposed to put this handler code? like inside me run function or just inside the button click?